# Chain events from a Webbrowser control

Tags: c#

I have nested lists that contain commands(strings) like Navigate, Type, Click, etc.

I'm trying to make these commands/events run one after another.
Here is a scenario:

```
Navigate("http://google.com")
Type("Something") // The field identificator is passed to the method too
Click("SomeButton")
```

The problem I'm facing is if I put the events in the DocumentLoaded event, it will fire just the next one(Type("Something")) without clicking the button.
I don't know if I have to create custom events or something else. I can easily make it for this scenario, but the thing is that the commands will be different and for different websites.

Here is some code that hopefully will make the question clear enough:

```
List<string> commandsList = new List<string>();
//[0] => navigate>http://google.com
//[1] => type>name>q>value
//[2] => click>name>btnK

private void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
                return;

            doAction(commandsList[1]);
            // how to "fire" commandsList[2] ?
        }

private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            doAction(commandsList[0]); // First action is always navigation
        }

private void doAction(List<string> commands)
        {
            // Do something with the WebBrowser(fill fields, etc.). Depends on the commands list.
        }
```

Comment: `but the thing is that the commands will be different and for different websites.` As you already noticed, There isn't a single solution that applies to all cases. This is why people try to use the APIs(if available) instead of trying to parse html pages.

Comment: Yes, but if I manage to execute the commands from commandsList consequently, this will solve my problem.

Comment: `I can easily make it for this scenario`, then do it for this *scenario*. But don't expect a generic way. (If that site wanted you to use it programatically, it would provide some APIs, so no generic way to hack)

Comment: I don't believe that it's not possible to "control" the browser with text commands, passed one after another.

if(command == "navigate")
{
webBrowser.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/");
}

Damn, I suck at explaining stuff in english :\

Comment: I don't say it is not possible. What I say is, there is no a generic formula to work for all sites. Since you said you know how you can do it for that scenario, **do it**.

Comment: Try looking at [WatiN](http://watin.org/)

Comment: The idea of a state machine is generally correct.  You however applied it completely wrong, you are not incrementing state correctly.  The band-aid is to just append doAction(commandList[2]);

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know how to apply it properly...
What do you mean with append to doAction(commandList[2]);?

Comment: Are you saying this is a duplicate of the question you edited to point to? Also, please don't deface your post. If its a duplicate, I'll close it as such.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is translate these:

```
Navigate("http://google.com")
Type("Something") // The field identificator is passed to the method too
Click("SomeButton")
```

To DOM level related things.  The first is simply calling a wrapper http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate(v=vs.110).aspx

The type command requires you to 1) Get the element ID and manipulate the value.

Finally the click event is simply 1) Get the element ID and invoke the CLICK method.

But as others said there's a lot of things that need to be known for example what element id's or Names do you want?